# Path problems with Texlive

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, kpsewhich

I'm having path problems (no doubt of my own making) resulting from first installing then uninstalling MikTex, then installing TeXlive, then initiating --usermode in the tlmgr (which I don't think I need).

I can run pdflatex, biber, bib2gls, and other binaries from a command line interface (CLI command `which pdflatex biber bib2gls` finds the correct binaries in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` and uses those. However, `kpsewhich` does not find any of those binaries, which is why I suspect it's a path problem.

Output from `tlmgr conf` yields the following:

```
=========================== version information ==========================
tlmgr revision 59291 (2021-05-21 05:14:40 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2021
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2021
==================== executables found by searching PATH =================
PATH: /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/chaoborid/.fzf/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/chaoborid/.local/bin:/home/chaoborid/.cargo/bin:/home/chaoborid/.local/share/applications:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf:/usr/local/texlive/2021:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/home/chaoborid/.local/bin/:/home/chaoborid/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/chaoborid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0-Ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin/python3:/opt/texbin
dvipdfmx:  /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/dvipdfmx
dvips:     /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/dvips
fmtutil:   /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil
kpsewhich: /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
luatex:    /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/luatex
mktexpk:   /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexpk
pdftex:    /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex
tex:       /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
tlmgr:     /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
updmap:    /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap
xetex:     /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xetex
=========================== active config files ==========================
config.ps:        /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config/dvips/config/config.ps
fmtutil.cnf:      /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktex.cnf:        /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/mktex.cnf
pdftexconfig.tex: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex
texmf.cnf:        /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf
texmf.cnf:        /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
updmap.cfg:       /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
============================= font map files =============================
kanjix.map:  /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map
pdftex.map:  /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
ps2pk.map:   /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
psfonts.map: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
ENCFONTS=.:{{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
SYSTEXMF=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var:/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}/dvips//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
TEXMF={{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config
TEXMFDBS={!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}
TEXMFDIST=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist
TEXMFHOME=/home/chaoborid/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR=/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
VARTEXFONTS=/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var/fonts
WEB2C={{}/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-config,/home/chaoborid/.texlive2021/texmf-var,/home/chaoborid/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist}/web2c
==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====
```

I think the problem is `$TEXMFHOME`, which points to `$HOME/texmf`, which does not contain the full set of TL programs, and I assume that `kpsewhich` should be looking somewhere in `/usr/local/texlive/2021`; presumably, `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux`, which *does* contain the proper binaries. But I'm not sure.

I can compile documents both from the command line and my editor (TeXstudio). However, in my editor, I had to explicitly point to each binary in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` for it to work (again, hinting at the same problem). My editor won't retrieve package texdoc because it can't find texlive.tlpdb (which also hints at the same problem).

Two questions: If the reason `kpsewhich` can't find my binaries is a path problem, which path should it be pointing to? How does one go about changing that path?

I'm running on Linux Pop!_OS 21.04. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: do you start the editor from the commandline or directly from the desktop, in the latter case make sure the usr/local/texlive... bin directory is in the path of the shell controlling the desktop. Your description suggests that the PATH is not set

Comment: That was it (for the editor, that is). Thank you. When I started the editor from the command line, all was as it should be. I start the editor from a rofi implementation in i3wm. It hadn't dawned on me that the path wasn't set. However, it doesn't solve the other problem that kpsewhich doesn't seem to see my TL binaries.

Comment: I don't understand your kpsewhich issue. binaries are not found via kpsewhich, they are found using the PATH and your shell. If `kpsewhich article.cls` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls` it is working as expected, if not what does it return?